# Convert data from a varying number of Column B cells to a single comma separated row based on Column A data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to reformat a large export of images from Shopify.

They have been exported in this format:

```
 A        B
SKU | img source
1755  http://img1.jpg
      http://img2.jpg
      http://img3.jpg
1756  http://img1.jpg 
      http://img2.jpg
1757  http://img1.jpg
```

Each sku has a different amount of images. I need all the urls to be in a comma separated list in one row, (the same as the sku) and then whenever a new value appears in column A, it needs to restart with the matching column B value as the first in the list and so on and so forth.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have `TEXTJOIN()`?

Comment: I did not have access to it, I ended up solving it as such

10 was the most amount of images so I did a simple (but slightly tedious) concatenation of 10 cells with commas in between, then expanded the formula all the way down the sheet. Then I deleted the blank rows (after pasting values) and voila! there will be some extra commas at the end but I think I can remove those. (haven't quite gotten that far yet)

Comment: Sure you can find a UDF online for doing multiple concatenation.

Comment: for the record, here is the macro that worked for this

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is the macro that worked

```
Sub Delimit()
rownum = 3 'update to the correct starting row
outputRow = 1 'starting row for the output table
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
While rownum <= lastrow
    SKU = Cells(rownum, "A")
    delimited = Cells(rownum, "B")
    rownum = rownum + 1
    While (Cells(rownum, "A") = SKU Or Len(Cells(rownum, "A")) = 0) And rownum <= lastrow
        delimited = delimited & "," & Cells(rownum, "B")
        rownum = rownum + 1
    Wend
    Cells(outputRow, "D") = SKU           'change "D" to appropriate output column
    Cells(outputRow, "E") = delimited     'change "E" to appropriate output column
    outputRow = outputRow + 1
Wend
End Sub
```